# JAVA - Abstraction

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, abstraction, data-hiding

I am little confused about abstraction in java.

I have checked many pages stating that abstraction is data hiding(Hiding the implementation).

What I understand about abstraction is it is 'partial implementation'. Just define what you are going to need in an abstract class/interface and afterwards extend/implement them and add your own functionality.

What I don't understand is how this is a data hiding? You are going to get access to the code once you implement the class/interface and you will modify it according to your need.

I have checked many questions, articles on this but still confused about this.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It is not hiding it from you, but from the client.

Comment: Client? But what do he care about code?

Comment: Are you talking about abstract classes in general? interfaces? polymorphism?

Comment: Not the customer. The client refers to any code that uses your abstraction. I will make an answer to provide some code examples.

Comment: About abstraction. How it is data hiding? And if it is then hiding from whom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an example help you better. Suppose you want to implement a Graph class which may be have adjacency list or adjacency matrix to represent its nodes. So in abstract you want to "addNode" "addEdge" to this graph at least:

```
public abstract class Graph
{
    public abstract int addNode();
    public abstract void addEdge(int from, int to);
}
```

Now you can extend two classes:

```
public class GraphAdjList extends Graph
{
    private Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> adjListsMap;
    public int addNode()
    {
        //list based implementation 
    }
    public void addEdge(int from, int to)
    {
        //list based implementation
    }
}

public class GraphAdjMatrix extends Graph
{
    private int[][] adjMatrix;
    public int addNode()
    {
        //matrix based implementation 
    }
    public void addEdge(int from, int to)
    {
        //matrix based implementation
    }
}
```

when you call either of addEdge from these two classes you don't have to worry about the data structure behind it, you just know that you get the result you needed so for example:

```
Graph g1,g2;
g1 = new GraphAdjList();
g2 = new GraphAdjMatrix();

g1.addEdge(1,2);
g2.addEdge(1,2);
```

through polymorphism you call two different functions but get the same result as client of the Graph.

Another real life example would be car brakes. As a car client, the manufacturer gives you a pedal to push without knowing what is the implementation of the brake in the back-end. It can be a drum-brake or disc-brake implementation in the back. All you need is to push the brake!

Comment: Yes, that is convenient. In hindi we have one say for this - "Eat mangos, no need to count trees". Hope you understand :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing *abstraction* (the programming pattern) with the *abstract* keyword of the Java language. Despite the similitude, they are only very lightly related semantically.

- *Abstraction* means that you hide the implementation details from the code that uses a class or method. The code using your method does not need to know that you are implementing say, a List, using arrays or dynamic pointers or an embedded database or files in a filesystem.
- *abstract* is used to mark classes that have methods that are only declared and not implemented. It is "abstract" in the sense that they cannot be instantiated, you cannot create any instances out of these classes (but you can create them out of their concrete subclasses).

Answer (score 1):

Data hiding is when you cannot understand how to work API internally (for example, `ArrayList`) without reading the documentation. API creators don't provide any access to the array that underlies there.

You hide API implementation from users that will be used it. They shouldn't worry about how it works internally, they are only interested in the functionality which is provided to them.

There is [a good article](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_05.htm) about that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but if you're talking about abstract classes in general, they are there to provide functionality to a child class that extends it without the child class having to know or deal with all the details of the implementation (it's hidden from the user of the child class).

Let's take a car for example:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    protected int _numberOfWheels;
    public Vehicle() {
        this._numberOfWheels = 4;
    }
}

public class Truck extends Vehicle {
    public int carryingLoad;
    public Truck() {
        this.carryingLoad = 4000; // kg or something
    }
}
```

So vehicle is an abstract instance of a vehicle object and already has some functionality associated with it, such as the number of wheels. It's a protected method, so if I create a new instance of truck:

```
// Inside main
Truck truck = new Truck();
```

I cannot change the number of wheels, however, if I were to write a function for truck within the class like:

```
// Inside the Truck class
public void addSpareTire() {
    this._numberOfWheels++;
}
```

So that I could call it like:

```
// Inside main
truck.addSpareTire();
```

I could still interact with some variables, but only thorough the functions in the class that extends the abstract class. I can add one tire at a time by calling `addSpareTire()`, but I could never interact directly with `_numberOfWheels` from the main function where I am *using* the `Truck` object, but I can from inside the `Truck` class *declaration*. From the *user* of the truck object, that information is *hidden*.

I don't know if this is what you're asking for. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In Object oriented programming  **Abstraction is a process of hiding the implementation details from the user**, only the functionality will be provided to the user. In other words user will have the information on what the object does instead of how it does it.

check the following link for more details:
http://www.visionsdeveloper.com/tutorial/java/java-abstraction.jsp

Answer (score 1):

> You are going to get access to the code once you implement the class/interface and you will modify it according to your need.

I guess you are little confused about the concepts which language gives you like `Abstraction` here. You always have access to your own code but the things like `Abstraction` OR `Polymorphism` gives you the ideal ways which things must be. So in `Abstraction` you are just saying I know there will be a behavior having name `someThing` as abstract method but right now you dont know how it will behave, The implementer will tell us how this will be. See following code.

```
abstract class Game{
 public abstract void play();
}

class Football extends Game{
  @Override
  public abstract void play(){
      // write how football play
  }
}

class Cricket extends Game{
  @Override
  public abstract void play(){
      // write how Cricket play
  }
}
```

I am here leaving a question for you.

`Why you are making class level attributes public/protected/private although you have access to the code when you implement?`

Comment: So that I can control its accessibility.

Comment: yeah right! even you ave access to the code , But you do because accessibility matter :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about two things

1. Abstract concept in OOPs and its implementation in Java
2. abstract class in java
3. **Abstract :** There is OOPs concept called Abstract. Here, user can capture  necessary features of an object. This abstract concept implemented as class and object in java. So, coming to you question, data hiding, when you capture important features of an object in the form of class those features are accessible only to their own class's object. Here, you are hiding all features of a class from outside the class/world. So, it is called as data hiding
4. **abstract class :** This is the feature of the Java implementation. If you don't know complete implementation then you can go for abstract class of java.

Hope this helps you to understand a little

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not hiding the information from you, but from the client of your abstraction. Take a look at this example.

```
public class Demo {
    Client client = new Client(new Implementation());
}

public interface Abtraction {
    void doWork();
}

public class Implementation implements Abtraction{
    @Override
    public void doWork() {
        //doingTheWork
    }
}

public class Client{
    private Abtraction theAbstraction;

    public Client(Abstraction theAbstraction){
        this.theAbstraction = theAbstraction;
    }
}
```

The class `Client` is unaware of the implementation of `Abstraction`, this means that the `Demo` class can provide different implementations of `Abstraction` without messing up the `Client`.

Answer (score 0):

**Data Hiding** is basically hiding details about internal Data Members of a class and only **exclusively** giving the concerned class access to it.

Thus it avoids unnecessary penetration from other classes in the application or from any other application, meaning other classes cannot access private member variables directly.

Thus in this way you **abstract** internal details of the concerned class.